# How to run android app on real device in Fleet IDE

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, jetbrains-fleet

I want to run my app on my real device using Fleet IDE, I can run on emulator, but I dont see an option to run on real device. I cam see run configrations in **run.json**. Can you help me what to set in **destination** for my real device?

**run.json**

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "composeApp",
            "type": "android-app",
            "workingDir": "D:\\Murti\\HabitSensei",
            "allowParallelRun": true,
            "module": "HabitSensei.composeApp.main",
            "destination": "Pixel 2 API 31"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to use adb device name in destination, but it didn't work

Comment: The device should be visible in the completion options. 

If that's not the case and the device is visible in Android studio, then perhaps the logs could help.

Comment: Connect your device to the system. Verify that the device is connected using the ADB command. Copy the emulator settings and adjust the destination to match your real device (This will likely be auto-completed). That's all!

Comment: I have successfully connected the device and 'adb devices' is showing the device. However, autocomplete is not working in 'run.json' and I am unsure of what to set as the destination manually.